# System.InvalidOperationException: No XAML was found at the location

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

I have a wp7 app using the galasoft mvvm light toolkit. It is weird that the url is getting malformed at the time of navigation even though my code is creating the right url for navigation

The uri that is being generated is something like this from the exception

> {"No XAML was found at the location '/Views/EditItemGroupid=3.xaml'."}

Any ideas why the url would be like that. Just breaking my head over this.

Thanks

On the xaml side..

```
<ListBox x:Name="ItemGroupsList" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding ItemGroups}" 
         Height="496" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemGroup, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
        <Custom:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand 
                x:Name="SelectionChangedEvent" 
                Command="{Binding GoToEditItemGroupCommand, Mode=OneWay}" 
                PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
        </Custom:EventTrigger>
    </Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
```

The code on my view model

```
GoToEditItemGroupCommand = new RelayCommand(() => this.GoToPage(
    "EditItemGroup",
    string.Format("id={0}", SelectedItemGroup != null
        ? SelectedItemGroup.ItemGroupId : 0)
));

protected object GoToPage(string pageName, string queryString)
{
    var msg = new GoToPageMessage()
    {
        PageName = pageName, 
        QueryString =  queryString
    };
    Messenger.Default.Send<GoToPageMessage>(msg); 
    return null;
}
```

The code in my view code behind in the constructor
  Messenger.Default.Register(this, (action) => this.ReceiveMessage(action));

The code in the receivemessage method

```
private object ReceiveMessage(GoToPageMessage action)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("/Views/");
    sb.Append(action.PageName);
    sb.Append(".xaml");

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(action.QueryString))
    {
        sb.Append("?");
        sb.Append(action.QueryString);
    }

    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(sb.ToString(), UriKind.Relative));

    return null;
}
```

The GoToPageMessage is defined as

```
public class GoToPageMessage
{
    public string PageName { get; set; }

    public string QueryString { get; set; }
}
```

More exception details... sorry this may come out ugly

- AbsolutePath    'e.Uri.AbsolutePath' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'  string {System.InvalidOperationException}
- base    {"This operation is not supported on a relative URI."}  System.SystemException {System.InvalidOperationException}
- AbsoluteUri 'e.Uri.AbsoluteUri' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'   string {System.InvalidOperationException}
- Authority   'e.Uri.Authority' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' string {System.InvalidOperationException}
- DnsSafeHost 'e.Uri.DnsSafeHost' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'   string {System.InvalidOperationException}
- Fragment    'e.Uri.Fragment' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'  string {System.InvalidOperationException}
      HasAuthority    false   bool
- Host    'e.Uri.Host' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'  string {System.InvalidOperationException}
- HostNameType    'e.Uri.HostNameType' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'  System.UriHostNameType {System.InvalidOperationException}
      HostType    HostNotParsed   System.Uri.Flags
      IsAbsoluteUri   false   bool
- IsDefaultPort   'e.Uri.IsDefaultPort' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' bool {System.InvalidOperationException}
      IsDosPath   false   bool
      IsFile  Could not evaluate expression   bool
      IsImplicitFile  false   bool
- IsLoopback  'e.Uri.IsLoopback' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'    bool {System.InvalidOperationException}
      IsNotAbsoluteUri    true    bool
- IsUnc   'e.Uri.IsUnc' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' bool {System.InvalidOperationException}
      IsUncOrDosPath  false   bool
      IsUncPath   false   bool
- LocalPath   'e.Uri.LocalPath' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' string {System.InvalidOperationException}
      m_Flags HostNotParsed   System.Uri.Flags
      m_Info  null    System.Uri.UriInfo
      m_OrigFileString    null    string
      m_String    "/Views/EditItemGroupid=3.xaml" string
- m_Syntax    null    System.UriParser
      OriginalString  "/Views/EditItemGroupid=3.xaml" string
- PathAndQuery    'e.Uri.PathAndQuery' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'  string {System.InvalidOperationException}
- Port    'e.Uri.Port' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'  int {System.InvalidOperationException}
- PrivateAbsolutePath 'e.Uri.PrivateAbsolutePath' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'  string {System.NullReferenceException}
- Query   'e.Uri.Query' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' string {System.InvalidOperationException}
- Scheme  'e.Uri.Scheme' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'    string {System.InvalidOperationException}
      SecuredPathIndex    0   ushort
      Segments    Could not evaluate expression   string[]
      Syntax  Could not evaluate expression   System.UriParser
      UserDrivenParsing   false   bool
      UserEscaped false   bool
- UserInfo    'e.Uri.UserInfo' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'  string {System.InvalidOperationException}

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code if you want people to put effort into answering your questions.

Comment: What line causes the exception to be thrown? Have you traced out the value of your StringBuilder before you construct the Uri?

Comment: Is the error caused by `new Uri(sb.ToString(), UriKind.Relative)` or by `NavigationService.Navigate`? Whar is the content of `sb.ToString()` that you pass to `new Uri? Have you recompoled (not just compiled)?

Comment: The sb.ToString() has the url formatted correctly  /Views/EditItemGroup.xaml?id=somenumber  I have done rebuild, deployed and all of them.  The bug seems to be happening in the NavigationService.Navigate .

Comment: and also .. I am using messenging framework from the mvvm light framework. The view model sends a message to navigate to the view.. the view receives the message and then navigates to another view

Answer (score 2):

After upgrading a WP7 app to WP8 (VS 2013 RC), I got this very annoying error when trying to run the app in the emulator. `no xaml was found at the location ‘/mainpage.xaml`'.

I discovered a one line fix; In the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file, you have to change the line:

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)]
```

To

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en")]
```

One line fix!. Pity the error message is not helpful at all.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the rewriting that is done within the `Navigate` method, I would assume that you use an URL mapper that might cause the problem. To make it work adjust your URI mapping or remove the Mapper.

See [here](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/All-about-UriMapping-in-WP7) for more information about WP 7 URI mapping.

Comment: How do I adjust the uri mapping or remove the mapper